# How can i add modules to the requirements.psd1 in Azure for powershell Function App?

Tags: azure, powershell

I wrote the following in my powershell function app:

```
param($Timer)
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}
# Write an information log with the current time.
 Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"


$connectionString = "<connectionstring>"
$querystr = "select * from MyTable
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $querystr -OutputSqlErrors $true
```

The requirements.psd1 has the following:

```
  @{
    'Az' = '10.*'    
  }
```

It gives an error when i run it :

```
ERROR: The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.     
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException
```

what do i need to include in the file to make this work ?

Comment: Run the command `Install-Module sqlserver` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` Cmdlet is part of [`SqlServer`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/22.1.1) module. Hence the final `requirements.psd1` file should looks like this:

```
@{
   'Az' = '10.*' 
   'SqlServer' = '22.*'    
 }
```

Comment: did that , no difference , same error.

Comment: Is there a sample powershell function app that uses invoke-sqlcmd ?

Answer (score 0):

Create Powershell Azure function locally and deploy it to Azure functionapp.

Steps to follow:

1. Open command prompt=>sign in to Azure using command `az login`.
2. Install `Azure function core tools` using command `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true`.
3. **Create Azure function using commands:**

```
func init --worker-runtime powershell
func new
```

[image]

**Files of the created function:**
[image]

**To resolve the error, you need to install `SqlServer module`.**

- Install the `Sqlserver module` with the command **`Install-Module sqlserver`**:
- You can check if the `Invoke-sqlcmd` is available in the installed `SqlServer module` with the command **`Get-Command -Module SqlServer`**.

[image]

[image]

- Import the Module with the command **`Import-Module sqlserver`**:

Then as ***@Abdul Niyas P M*** mentioned, add `'SqlServer' = '22.*'` in the `requirements.psd1`.

After following above steps, I ran the same code in my environment.

```
param($Timer)

$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"

$connectionString = "<sql_server_connection_string>"
$querystr = "select * from Persons;"
Import-Module sqlserver
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $querystr -OutputSqlErrors $true
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I now get the error:  [Error] Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function

Comment: could that be with connecting to the db ?

Comment: here is the error:   Error: 'Failed to install function app dependencies. Error: 'The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to save the module 'SqlServer'.''

Comment: Did you important the module? try running the `Import-Module sqlserver` in the code itself. Use my updated code.

Comment: I have tried that no difference

Comment: Can you run this command `Get-Command -Module SqlServer` and share the screenshot of response here.

Comment: run it in kudu ?

Comment: Are you trying to run your function in Azure Portal? If yes, try it in local and deploy to azure.

Comment: yes trying in azure .. i havent done locally and deployed .

Comment: But can i write a powershell function app , test locally and then deploy ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255653/discussion-between-traci-and-pravallika-kv).